# Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this queries -

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `hotel`;

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
DROP USER 'user'@'localhost';

CREATE USER user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'user';

CREATE DATABASE `hotel`
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

GRANT USAGE ON *.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'user';
```

But I always get error on

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table    0.000 sec
```

I thought that `Grant usage` create new user if user does not exist. What is wrong?

Comment: Single quotes `CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';` - ?

Comment: Hm. Yes. It is single quote.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I thought that Grant usage create new user if user does not exist. What is wrong?

In previous versions of mysql that was the case.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072858/411177) if you want to do it the new way.  If you would like to modify your system settings to make it work the way it used to, read on.  However, note that this is a deprecated behavior, as the linked documentation states that

> NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER will be removed in a future MySQL
>       release, at which point its effect will be enabled at 
>       all times (GRANT will not create accounts)

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user), you can set an option to allow mysql to create a user if it does not exist.

> NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
>
> Prevent the GRANT statement from automatically creating new users if
>   it would otherwise do so, unless a nonempty password also is
>   specified.

To set the option:

> You can change the SQL mode at runtime by using a SET [GLOBAL|SESSION]
>   sql_mode='modes' statement to set the sql_mode system value.

Comment: run `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` to check if `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` is present of not. If present, then create a set operation with no `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`. e.g. `set sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

Answer (score 112):

I got the same error with

```
grant all on newdb.* to newuser@localhost;
```

solved with 'identified by':

```
grant all on newdb.* to newuser@localhost  identified by 'password';
```

Comment: weird, why do i need this when i'm root

Comment: I just forgot `@localhost` and that's why iI was getting this error.

Comment: ospider, it's because you identify a new user, you grant privileges too

Answer (score 20):

The [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) command no longer automatically creates users.

Do not change the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` variable, instead first create the user using the `CREATE USER` command, *then* grant the privileges:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'user'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Worked for me as well for a issue of access-denied for 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' which prevented me from doing *service mysql restart*

Answer (score 4):

Try to add to the end of the script:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```