# mysql 5.7 can't allow docker IP access on CentOS7

Tags: mysql, docker, centos

I've installed Mysql5.7 and docker service on CentOS 7.1. It's ok that connect mysql with command `mysql -u root` locally. But it's fail to connect when I tried to use `mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.1`, in which `172.17.0.1` is the local docker0 ip address.

```
[root@test1 workspace]# mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.1
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'test1.novalocal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I've googled the reason and trying to grant access to `test1.novalocal` but without lucky.

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to root@'test1.novalocal' with grant option;
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Any other clue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597144/cant-find-any-matching-row-in-the-user-table

Comment: Try setting --skip-name-resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'test1.novalocal' identified by 'somepassword' with grant option;
```

MySQL latest versions comes with [NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user) which

> Prevent the GRANT statement from automatically creating new users if
>   it would otherwise do so, unless authentication information is
>   specified. The statement must specify a nonempty password using
>   IDENTIFIED BY or an authentication plugin using IDENTIFIED WITH.

You may [disable](https://support.kayako.com/article/472-how-do-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode-on-the-server) this mode if needed to go with blank password!

MySQL Workbench even warns

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Using GRANT for creating new
>   user is deprecated and will be removed in future release.

You may need to [CREATE a user before GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

172.17.0.1 is the docker0 ip, not your container ip.

You can get your container ip via `docker inspect yourcontainerid`

Comment: I am not trying to get container IP, instead I need container to access mysql which was installed on host.