# "Can't find any matching row in the user table" after upgrading mysql from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, travis-ci, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6, azerothcore

I'm getting this error:

> Can't find any matching row in the user table

When trying to execute this line of my CI script:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'host' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

I know that similar questions have been already asked:

[Can't find any matching row in the user table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597144/cant-find-any-matching-row-in-the-user-table)

[MySQL Error #1133 - Can't find any matching row in the user table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877458/mysql-error-1133-cant-find-any-matching-row-in-the-user-table)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69921/error-code-1133-cant-find-any-matching-row-in-the-user-table

however, none of them solved my issue.

In particular, in my case, this issue started after I've upgraded my travis-ci from using ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, which also changed the **MySQL version from 5.6 to 5.7**.

So I'm sure the same code works with MySQL 5.6 but not with MySQL 5.7.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new username? You should use `CREATE USER` first.

Comment: @barmar why wasn't it required on mysql 5.6 ?

Comment: Actually, the change I was thinking of is in MySQL 8.0, not 5.7. They removed the ability to create users with `GRANT`. So I think this should work in 5.7.

Comment: @Barmar your solution solved the issue, would you like to post it as normal answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 they changed the default SQL modes to include [`NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`](https://ideone.com/g1m5A2). This prevents `GRANT` from creating users, so you have to use `CREATE USER` instead. You can also remove this setting from the SQL mode of your server.

This change was in preparation for 8.0, which removes the ability of `GRANT` to create users entirely.